# How to apply a command on all fields of one specific column?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a command `cmd` that takes a string as parameter and return another string.

I need to apply this command to one specific column of a file formated in a 5x7 table (say the 3rd column), so that instead of having

```
string11 string12 string13 string14 string15 string16 string17
string21 string22 string23 string24 string25 string26 string27
string31 string32 string33 string34 string35 string36 string37
string41 string42 string43 string44 string45 string46 string47
string51 string52 string53 string54 string55 string56 string57
```

I have

```
string11 string12 $(cmd string13) string14 string15 string16 string17
string21 string22 $(cmd string23) string24 string25 string26 string27
string31 string32 $(cmd string33) string34 string35 string36 string37
string41 string42 $(cmd string43) string44 string45 string46 string47
string51 string52 $(cmd string53) string54 string55 string56 string57
```

where `$(cmd string<i><j>)` represent the string output resulting from applying `cmd` to `string<i><j>`

**How to apply a custom command `cmd` to a arbitrary column number of a file formatted as a table?**

PS: I would prefer using `awk` rather than `sed`.

Comment: What exactly is the command you want to apply ? can you please explain a little more in detail ? AWK can work with columns, but we need to know what exactly to do with that column

Answer (score 3):

With `gawk` (and likely with `nawk` - but not, as far as I can tell, with `mawk`) you should be able to do that using the `"command" | getline variable` form of `getline`.

For example, with the following script as a test `cmd` that takes a single string parameter and outputs its upper-case version

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s' "$1" | sed 's/.*/\U&/'
```

then with your sample input as `file`

```
$ gawk '{"./cmd "$3 | getline $3}1' file
string11 string12 STRING13 string14 string15 string16 string17
string21 string22 STRING23 string24 string25 string26 string27
string31 string32 STRING33 string34 string35 string36 string37
string41 string42 STRING43 string44 string45 string46 string47
string51 string52 STRING53 string54 string55 string56 string57
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a not very well known feature of `sed` that allows you to execute a command. This is for GNU sed and is called with `/e`:

```
$ sed 's/1/echo 555/e' <<< "123"
55523
```

In our case, let's catch the block and process it through the given `cmd`:

Firstly, by catching the groups properly:

```
$ sed -r 's/^((\w+\W+){2})\w+(.*)/printf "%s%s%s" "\1" "\2" "\3"/e' file
string11 string12 string12  string14 string15 string16 string17
string21 string22 string22  string24 string25 string26 string27
string31 string32 string32  string34 string35 string36 string37
string41 string42 string42  string44 string45 string46 string47
string51 string52 string52  string54 string55 string56 string57
```

This basically captures the whole line and prints it back through `printf` and using the captured groups as arguments. You see now it is a bit silly, because it just prints back.

Since you can to perform `cmd` against the given string, you should use:

```
sed -r 's/^((\w+\W+){2})\w+(.*)/printf "%s%s%s" "\1" "$(cmd "\2")" "\3"/e' file
```

Say `cmd` is `awk 'BEGIN {print 1}'`, then we would say:

```
$ sed -r 's/^((\w+\W+){2})\w+(.*)/printf "%s%s%s" "\1" "$(awk "BEGIN{print 1}")" "\3"/e' file
string11 string12 1 string14 string15 string16 string17
string21 string22 1 string24 string25 string26 string27
string31 string32 1 string34 string35 string36 string37
string41 string42 1 string44 string45 string46 string47
string51 string52 1 string54 string55 string56 string57
```

As you see, the idea here is

All of this is based on [Sed replace with the output of a bash command using capture group as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39350238/1983854) which I created based on [How to change date format in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34080390/1983854).